# List to store data generate by split method

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to split an input string based on space .
i/p : `"darshan kamat"`

I need to split above string into 2 different tags in FTL .

expected o/p :

```
<fname>darshan</fname>
<lname>kamat</lname>
```

But with split i am just able to iterate print same output which does not help

```
<#list name?split("\\s+", "r") as x>
${x}
</#list>
```

With <#assign var= List> throws error as it expects string only
How to store and access list, something like {x[0]} ,{x[1]}
Any pointers please as how to approach?

Comment: `#assign` supports all types, not just strings. The mistake people often do, and what maybe you did is writing `<#assign x="${someExpression}">` (that's a string interpolation, which therefore must conver to string), instead of the correct `<#assign x=someExpression>` (no type conversion there). Then `x[0]`, etc. should work as well. If it still won't work, provide failing example.

Comment: You are right I made the same mistake . We can store lists with assign as well